# Linq to objects using 'not exists' and 'group by'?

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I've been assigned a new project at work which uses NHibernate. A query that I can easily write in sql has me totally stumped on how to do it in linq, which is how I've been told to do it.

So, here's the query:

```
select  ts.BatchID, COUNT(distinct ts.UniqID) SurveyCount
from    TeleformStaging.TeleformStaging ts
where   ts.IsRescan = 0
and     not exists (select  bfr.BatchID
                    from    TeleformStaging.BatchesForRescan bfr
                    where   bfr.BatchTrack = ts.BatchID)
group by ts.BatchID
order by ts.BatchID
```

I believe I could get the 'group by' portion, but no idea on the subquery.

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Even if you figure out how to write this in LINQ, your LINQ provider might have trouble converting it to SQL. You might have to try several different versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result= (
        from ts in db.TeleformStaging
        where ts.IsRescan == false //if is a boolean else == 0
        && 
        !(
            from bfr in db.BatchesForRescan
            select bfr.BatchTrack
        ).Contains(ts.BatchID)
        orderby ts.BatchID
        group ts by ts.BatchID into g
        select new
        {
            BatchID=g.Key,
            SurveyCount=g.Select (x =>x.UniqID).Distinct().Count()
        }
    );
```

where db is the linq data context

**Edit**

You could also do it with `.Any()`. Like this:

```
var result= (
        from ts in db.TeleformStaging
        where ts.IsRescan == false //if is a boolean else == 0
        && 
        !(
            from bfr in db.BatchesForRescan
            where ts.BatchID==bfr.BatchTrack
            select bfr.BatchTrack
        ).Any()
        orderby ts.BatchID
        group ts by ts.BatchID into g
        select new
        {
            BatchID=g.Key,
            SurveyCount=g.Select (x =>x.UniqID).Distinct().Count()
        }
    );
```

**Edit 1**

Useful links:

- [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)
- [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)
- [Simple group by](http://blog.csainty.com/2008/01/linq-to-sql-groupby.html)
- [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)
- [Order by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: I don't know what paths you travel in your everyday life, but it's certainly impressive that you could whip this up so fast. I'll start fiddling around with this and see if I can get it going (AND understand why it works). I appreciate your effort.

Comment: When you work with it, you do queries like this on daily bases and you supply us with sql. The languages are so simulare and it easy to whip it up :P.. I forgot the order by, added that. Added some link for you to read up on the functions used. Maybe you consider accepting the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

```
from fs in context.TeleformStaging
where !ts.IsRescan && !context.BatchesForRescan.Any(bfr=>bfr.BatchTrack == ts.BatchID)
group ts by ts.BatchID into g
    select new
    {
        BatchID=g.Key,
        SurveyCount=g.Select (x =>x.UniqID).Distinct().Count()
    }
```

with group by

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is slightly reversed, but does offer the complexity with a few lambda expressions; how does this look:

```
var result = from ts in TeleformStaging.TeleformStaging
                where !ts.IsRescan && !TeleformStaging.BatchesForRescan.Any(bfr => bfr.BatchID == ts.BatchID)
                group ts by ts.BatchID into tsGrouped
                orderby tsGrouped.Key
                select new
                {
                    BatchId = tsGrouped.Key,
                    SurveyCount = tsGrouped.Select(x => x.UniqID).Distinct().Count()
                };
```